# Different Users for Different "Sites" ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I am creating a web application that, simply put, allows for the users to create their own "sites" which have their own set of users.  I look at the domain name of the request coming in to determine which "site" to display.  I need to have completely different sets of users depending on which "site" you are on.  For example:  If I visit *site1.example.com* I am able to register as *bob*.  Trying to login to *site2.example.com* with my credentials from site1 would fail, because I don't have an account there.  Likewise, I should be able to create another, independent *bob* user on site2.  Therefore, not only will I need to store additional information with the user (like what site they registered on), I also need to make the username field non-unique.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  I would like to use the built-in security provider in ASP.NET, so I can use things like `[Authorize]`, but if some 3rd-party security suite would work, I am open to that as well.

Comment: Are the user credentials going to be stored in one database or each site have its own database?

Comment: IMHO, you should look at existing solutions for examples.  Here's a related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630151/how-is-multi-tenancy-done-in-the-orchard-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Asp.net membership provider ... one easy way is to change "role" s for each set of users. All users registered for site will get role "site1user" assigned. And so on. You can maintain all users in one database ... differentiated by roles.